# Is there a way to use nunjucks to transform a DOM structure into another?

Tags: javascript, dom, nunjucks, templating-engine

I frequently build webpages from InDesign exported HTML files. And in InDesign I have some control over the elements `class` attribute, but it is rather difficult to change the DOM structure itself.
And it is not always sufficient to go with the DOM it outputs so I need a way to transform the DOM.

The approach I had was to run a set of jquery commands on a puppeteer instance to imperatively shape the DOM and save the output HTML to a file. It became quite unmaintainable and it's very hard to tell from the code what are the expected input and output.

So I'm trying nunjucks as a template engine to generate the output. But AFAIK Nunjucks is good at printing previously defined variables, but doesn't provide any tools to retrieve its input from a HTML block

I want to write a template/macro with selectors that find the content in the input, kinda like this:

```html
<section>
    <header>
        <h2>{% contentFrom(".section-header") %}</h2>
    </header>
    <main>
        {% contentFrom(".content") %}
    </main>
</section>
```

And then just wrap my input in a nunjucks tag, like this

```html
{% filter dont_know_yet_what_should_go_in_here }
    <p class="section-header">My_header_here</p>
    <p class="content">My_contents</p>
{% endfilter}
```

I imagine this could be possible with nunjucks custom filters or custom tags. But if there is a much better solution, I'll accept that as an answer as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it!

In Nunjucks, one can wrap some html in a `{% call someMacro() %}` tag. This way, the `someMacro()` macro gets called with a bonus: The wrapped content can be used inside the macro through the `caller()` method.

But `caller()` returns the whole HTML chunk as a string, and I still need a way to parse it and pick only the elements I need. For that, I used [cheerio](http://cheerio.js.org/) along with some Nunjucks custom globals.

Since one can't run pure javascript inside Nunjucks templates, in my gulp setup, I defined an alias to cheerio's `load()` method and passed it to my nunjucks environment via a global variable (conveniently called `$`):

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

function cheer(html, selector) {
    var a = cheerio.load(html.toString())
    return a(selector)
}

var manageEnvironment = function(environment) {
    environment.addGlobal('$', cheer);
} // then pass manageEnvironment to Nunjucks initializer function
```

---

Then, in my template, I assign `caller()` to a variable, just to make it less verbose, and then I can use my function to select and modify the input DOM before it gets inserted into my template:

```
{% macro myComponent() %} 
{% set a = caller() %} {# Assigned caller to a shorter variable because it'll be repeated a few times #}


<section>
    <header>
        <h1>{{ $(a, '.box-title').html() }}</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        {{ $(a, '._obj_box *:not(.box-title)').html() }}
    </main>

    <footer style="border: 2px solid red;">
        {{ $(a, ".see_more-title").html() | urlize | safe }}
    </footer>

</section>

{% endmacro %}
```

Importante note: I don't know why, but Nunjucks always escaped the HTML returned from my `$()` method, even when I used the `safe` filter. Since I have a fully controlled environment, It was easier just to turn off auto escaping for the whole Nunjucks rendering.